# Twitter OAuth Delete Problem

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Im having a hard time getting Twitter to delete a status using the PHP OAuth library.

I am using this same method for posting (OAUTH_TYPE_FORM, and OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST), and it works well.

Here is my code for the Delete reques:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($twitter['CONSUMER_KEY'], $twitter['CONSUMER_SECRET'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);
$oauth->setToken($access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/destroy/".$delete_id, NULL, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

I keep receiving a 401 Error. Any help please advise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the *format* [http://api.twitter.com/version/statuses/destroy/:id.format](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/destroy/%3aid) which can be `xml` or `json`.

`$oauth->fetch("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/destroy/".$delete_id.".json", NULL, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);`

Also, `$delete_id` should be stored as a string as it might be too large to be represented as an integer properly in PHP.

ie) 
`$delete_id = 68090979596505088765 + "";` instead of
`$delete_id = 68090979596505088765;`